# Iterating over a large Django queryset while the data is changing elsewhere

Tags: python, django, django-models

Iterating over a queryset, like so:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # <snip some other stuff>
    activity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def calculate_statistics():
        self.activity = book.views * 4
        book.save()

def cron_job_calculate_all_book_statistics():
    for book in Book.objects.all():
        book.calculate_statistics()
```

...works just fine. However, this is a cron task. `book.views` is being incremented while this is happening. If `book.views` is modified while this cronjob is running, it gets reverted.

Now, `book.views` is not being modified by the cronjob, but it is being cached during the `.all()` queryset call. When `book.save()`, I have a feeling it is using the old `book.views` value.

Is there a way to make sure that only the `activity` field is updated? Alternatively, let's say there are 100,000 books. This will take quite a while to run. But the `book.views` will be from when the queryset originally starts running. Is the solution to just use an `.iterator()`?

**UPDATE:** Here's effectively what I am doing. If you have ideas about how to make this work well inline, then I'm all for it.

```
def calculate_statistics(self):
    self.activity = self.views + self.hearts.count() * 2
    # Can't do self.comments.count with a comments GenericRelation, because Comment uses
    # a TextField for object_pk, and that breaks the whole system. Lame.
    self.activity += Comment.objects.for_model(self).count() * 4
    self.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do the job for you in Django 1.1, no loop necessary:

```
from django.db.models import F
Book.objects.all().update(activity=F('views')*4)
```

You can have a more complicated calculation too:

```
for book in Book.objects.all().iterator():
    Book.objects.filter(pk=book.pk).update(activity=book.calculate_activity())
```

Both these options have the potential to leave the activity field out of sync with the rest, but I assume you're ok with that, given that you're calculating it in a cron job.

Comment: There is actually a lot of processing going on, including other fields. I just simplified it for the sake of this question. That would be a fine solution, but I've got a lot going on there that I don't think I can just inline.

Comment: I think you may have to live with the fact that 'activity' could be out of sync with other fields, which I assume you're already fine with, given that you're using a cron to update 'activity'. I've updated the answer to handle more complicated processing, while avoiding overwriting the object.

Comment: Added `.iterator()`, as mentioned by Alex.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have said if you are iterating over a large queryset you should use iterator():

```
Book.objects.filter(stuff).order_by(stuff).iterator()
```

this will cause Django to not cache the items as it iterates (which could use a ton of memory for a large result set).

Comment: .itertor() works great, but is there any way to "lock" the database so I can perform a read and then a subsequent write in an atomic fashion? Will this require dropping down to raw SQL, where it certainly is possible, or does Django provide a hook for this?

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you solve this, beware of transaction-related issues. E.g. default transaction isolation level is set to REPEATABLE READ, at least for MySQL backend. This, plus the fact that both Django and db backend work in a specific autocommit mode with an ongoing transaction means, that even if you use (very nice) *whrde* suggestion, value of `views' could be no longer valid. I could be wrong here, but feel warned.